# .net and dnn framework up-gradation

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, dotnetnuke

I am facing an issue while upgrading my application. My application was built on .net framework 2.0 and DNN 4.09. Now we are going through up-gradation of both. But how can i verify that my .net framework is now 3.5 ? whenever i get an exception it shows .net 2.0 on yellow screen of death. And after it i tried to upgrade my DNN 4.09 to 5.02. Application is running smooth but admin panel is showing many crashing.It shows crashing of htmlmodule.dll
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU0XG.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYdnl.png)

Answer (score 0):

In DNN you can view the .Net version under "Host > Host settings" select the tab "Basic Settings". You will see an "Configuration" section. Here you can find basic hosting environment settings. Note that the names of the pages and tabs can vary a bit from version to version.

You can also check in IIS itself what kind of .Net version the Application Pool is using.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the app pool .Net version in IIS.
Then in your application you will need to change the .Net version in the assembly info to build against the same version of the DotNetNuke.dll assembly you have referenced in the project.
Here is a link to how to update it in IIS: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/134981/upgrading-dotnetnuke-to-aspnet-40
If that doesn't work please attach a screenshot of the error.

Comment: as i said i've changed .net version to 3.5. we specify CLR version in IIS(If i am not wrong) and CLR version is same for both 3.5 and 2.0, therefore 3.5 is not listed in my apppool list.

Comment: Is everything in your DNN web config referencing 3.5 now? I assume the upgrade made these changes for you. You should see the new Linq assembly in the web config and your compiler versions updated to 3.5. Maybe make sure the .Net version of the assembly giving you the error isn't 4.0+ for some odd reason.